# Characterization of the matrices $C$ such that $AB=C \Leftrightarrow BA=C$ for any $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Two well-known results from Matrix Theory. Here, matrix means "square matrix of order $n$"; the scalar field can be anything.

1. We can find two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=0$ but $BA\neq 0$.
2. For any matrices $A$ and $B$, we have $AB=I$ if and only if $BA=I$.

I am interested into the characterization of the matrices $C$ having the same feature that $I$ above, namely that for any matrices $A$ and $B$, if $AB=C$, then $BA=C$. But I have no idea on where to start. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equations $AB=C$ and $BA=C$ imply $AC=ABA=CA$ for all $A$. This implies 
that $C$ is in the center of the matrix algebra $M_n(K)$, which consists of
all $\lambda I$ for $\lambda \in K$. Hence
$C=\lambda I$, with $\lambda\neq 0$. For $n=1$ also $C=0$ is possible.